# increasing amazon root volume size

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have a default amazon ec2 instance with  8GB root volume size. I am running out of space. I have:

1. Detach the current EBS volume in AWS Management Console (Web).
2. Create snapshot of this volume.
3. Created a new Volume with 50G space with my snapshot.
4. Attach the new volume back to the instance to /dev/sda1

However, when I reconnect to the account with:

`> df -h`

I can see from the management console that my new

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used   Available  Use%  Mounted on
/dev/xvda1       8256952   8173624        0     100%  /
tmpfs            308508        40    308468     1%    /dev/shm
```

It's still not using my new volume's size, how to make this work?

Comment: Did you mount the new EBS volume?

Comment: I guess it is a question for ServerFault rather then StackOverflow.

Answer (score 3):

You have enlarged the volume, but the filesystem size has remained the same. You should resize the file system. If it is ext3 and the kernel supports on-line resize this should work:

```
resize2fs /dev/xvda1
```